# Zend Framework / CSS (IE) isn't applying as it supposed to !

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, zend-framework

I have this really weird problem with Zend Framework and the view on all IE's
I'm using the HTML/CSS template for the sticky footer, where the page is also centralised in the middle of the screen. I used the same template before applying the design on the code on Zend and all browsers worked perfectly fine. Now when I applied the design on the code, all browsers are still working fine except of IE (7,8,9) ! The page isn't centralised any more, and some elements aren't taking their CSS classes. I copied the exact same code I used before moving the code to Zend (which was working on IE) and pasted it into Zend and I still had the same problem. I even created a div and tried to centralise it using the following CSS code:

```
#container{
position:absolute; 
width:960px;
height:200px;
left:50%;
top:0;
margin-left:-480px;
}
```

and still, it wasn't centralised on any of the IE browsers ...

Could anyone please try and help me figure out what exactly is going on??

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello again everyone ... I'm not sure if I'm supposed to apologise for the question or not, but after a really long time of research and many tries to fix the issue I had either by changing the HTML code or CSS, the solution was really easy (or maybe I was stupid I didn't pay attention for it). All I had to do was change the doctype of the document, once I added
    < !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> all the CSS bugs was fixed, the page was centralised and it worked perfectly fine.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try : `text-align:center;`

Another way to center content is to do so :

```
#container{
     width:960px;
     height:200px;
     position: absolute;
     margin 0 auto;
     text-align:center; 
}
```

Look : http://jsfiddle.net/5u8aM/

Comment: I used the HTML property "align:center" and used it on the wrapper DIV and the FOOTER DIV (that's cause the footer isn't in the wrapper) ... That fixed the centralising problem, but I still have a problem with some of the elements that are refusing to have any CSS property from the CSS files.

Comment: If you do a test and create #test in ur css with code like `color:yellow;` and the you add a div on your page like so : `<div id="test">blabla</div>` is blabla yellow? If no, the link to your css style sheet is wrong.

Comment: The link to my CSS is 100% right, the thing that is happening is that I'm using the same exact code, once in a regular html page, and once inside a Zend framework project, and on IE only, I'm getting 2 different results

Comment: Ok I see, it means there is something else outside this style sheet that is affecting the look of the page.

Comment: Exactly, I figured it out too and posted it as an answer for this question, you can check it out below ... Many thanks for your help David

Comment: Ahaha, I like the answer :D, I didn't think of it as a solution though. Good job!